# More than two-level with() in Yii?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I'm trying to do this:

```
$this->PickTicketLineModel->PickTicket->SO->CustomerShipToModel
```

If I go through each piece, I get a model for PickTicketLine, one for PickTicket, and one for SO.  When I get to CustomerShipToModel, I get back null.  Since this should match an existing row in the database, I'm assuming something is going wrong with the relation.  Any suggestions?

Pick Ticket Line Table Relations

```
'PickTicket' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblwhPickTicket', 'PickTicketNumber'),
```

Pick Ticket Table Relations

```
'SO' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblsoSO', 'SONumber'),
```

SO Table Relations

```
'CustomerShipToModel' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblarCustomerShipTo', 'CustomerShipTo'),
```

Customer Ship To Table Relations

```
'CustomerShipToModel' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblarsoSO', 'CustomerShipTo'),
```

This is how I got the PickTicketLine model in the first place:

```
$this->pickTicketLine = TblwhPickTicketLine::model()->with('PickTicket','PickTicket.SO')->FindByPk(array('PickTicketNumber'=>$pickTicketNumber, 'PickTicketLineNumber'=>$pickTicketLineNumber));
```

Comment: add together() chain before the with() chain, if doesn't work you need to turn on sql log and see what query is generated

Comment: together() didn't work, though I'm not sure what it was supposed to do.  For now I've just moved on to pulling the customerShipTo model separately using findByPk

Comment: U assign `$this->pickTicketLine`, but there using `$this->PickTicketLineModel`->PickTicket->SO->CustomerShipToModel, maybe: `$this->pickTicketLine`->PickTicket->SO->CustomerShipToModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to eager load all the related data explicitly:

```
$this->pickTicketLine = TblwhPickTicketLine::model()->with(array(
    'PickTicket' => array(
        'with' => array(
            'SO' => array(
                'with' => array('CustomerShipToModel')
            )
        )
    )        
))->findByPk(array(
    'PickTicketNumber'=>$pickTicketNumber,
    'PickTicketLineNumber'=>$pickTicketLineNumber
));
```

If that does not work, either, log your database requests and inspect the query, as suggested by Pentium10 in the comments. You could just let phpMyAdmin perform the query or use the MySQL "EXPLAIN" keyword for additional information. In order to get the relevant logs, you have to add the following lines to your config/main.php file:

```
'components'=>array(
    'db'=>array(
        'enableProfiling' => true,
        'enableParamLogging' => true
    )
)
```

Comment: you should be able to do ``with(array('PickTicket.SO.CustomerShipToModel'))``